# Loggin into the backend fails while using online CPANEL

Tags: php

Hello guys i have a sight i have built in xampp it works well that is it can log in to the dashboard without hustle and create session and the user can afterwards log out. but after I launched the site the user cannot log it the site is just not responding. the log in screen is on i tried changing the script and all i get is just a white page, if i put the right script it redirects to the same login page. my host uses linux cpanel and thats the terminal i am using. mind you the site works fine connects well to the db and it even pulls the users available in the db but they issue is in the back end. here is the code i am using..

```html
<?php 
/* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
require '../config/config.php';
session_start();
?>


<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

        require '../sessions/login.php';
        
    }
    
    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering
        
        require '../sessions/register.php';
        
    }
}
?>
<?php
 // Check if form submitted with method="post"
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) 
 {   
  if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
   
  $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE email='$email'");

  if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
  { 
   header("location: index.php?msg=".urlencode("User with this email does not exist!")); 
  }
  else { // User exists (num_rows != 0)

   $user = $result->fetch_assoc(); // $user becomes array with user data
   
   $email = $user['email'];
   $hash = $user['hash'];
   $first_name = $user['first_name'];

   // Send registration confirmation link (reset.php)
   $to      = $email;
   $subject = 'Password Reset Link (site )';
   $message_body = '
   Hello '.$first_name.',

   You have requested password reset!

   Please click this link to reset your password:

   http://sitename/reset.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash;  

   mail($to, $subject, $message_body);

   header("location: reset.php?msg=".urlencode("<p>Please check your email <span>$email</span>"
   . " for a confirmation link to complete your password reset!</p>")); 
   }
 }
 }
?>
```

**this is the login script**

```html
// Escape email to protect against SQL injections
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE email='$email'");

if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist

    header("location: index.php?msg=".urlencode("User with that email doesn't exist!"));
}
else { // User exists
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {
        
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['f_name'] = $user['f_name'];
        $_SESSION['l_name'] = $user['l_name'];
   $_SESSION['image'] = $user['image'];
   $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];
        
        // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else {
  
        header("location: ../index.php?msg=".urlencode('You have entered wrong password, try again!'));
    }
}


?>
```

If anyone have a clue ?

Comment: can you remove the CAPS from the title please? It's considered as you yelling to us.

Answer (score 0):

**White Screen Of Death**:

If you're seeing a blank page (and view-source is empty), make sure your `php.ini` contains `error_reporting = -1` and `display_errors = On` (only recommended for development). Putting:  at the top of your script might have no effect if your script fails to compile such as in the case of PARSE errors.

Your error will now appear on the page. However, that's not great for a live production system.

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to `-1`, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

Comment: Offline the site works well both the front end and back end but the moment i transfer the code to the online server front end works but  the back end doesn't plus i am just using a service provider to host my files and domain name.